# Why InputStreamReader doesn't read process' output in real time?

Tags: java, process, io, inputstream

I am trying to use `ProcessBuilder` to run some external commands, like `ifstat` or `vmstat` in Linux.

Such kinds of commands support custom sampling intervals. If I add a sample interval to the external command, for example, `ifstat 20`, then the command will output like this:

```
coolcfan@coolcfan-PC:~$ ifstat 20
       eth0               wlan0               vmnet1              vmnet8      
 KB/s in  KB/s out   KB/s in  KB/s out   KB/s in  KB/s out   KB/s in  KB/s out
```

after 20 seconds

```
   41.29      1.06      0.36      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
```

after another 20 seconds

```
   16.67      0.58      0.38      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
```

**However**, when I am running the command using my Java code, the first part of the output will be read after 20 seconds, like this:

```
Start running "ifstat 20"
```

after 20 seconds

```
       eth0               wlan0               vmnet1              vmnet8      
 KB/s in  KB/s out   KB/s in  KB/s out   KB/s in  KB/s out   KB/s in  KB/s out
   66.61      1.73      1.29      0.01      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
```

When I use a NIO server to run the command and use SocketChannel to send the output to the client, the problem is even more severe... (my client needs to wait another 20 seconds to get the output from server after server shows the first output which is 20 seconds after the process start)

And I noticed that the length of the delay of outputing is related to the interval I set to the command.

So why doesn't the ISR read the output in real time?

A simple test code snippet to demo my question:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();

    pb.command("ifstat 20".trim().split(" "));

    Process p = null;

    System.out.println("Start running \"ifstat 20\"");

    try {
        p = pb.start();

        char[] buf = new char[512];

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());

        int count = -1;

        while ((count = isr.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1) {
            System.out.print(new String(buf, 0, count));
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
    }
}
```

---

Update:

As Peter's comment, this is not a problem related to Java. It is a **piping delay**.

But I still don't understand, why `vmstat 20 | cat` doesn't have this delay, while `ifstat 20 | cat` will delay to show the heads?

Comment: ISR reads whatever you get.  For comparison run `ifstat 20 | cat` so that it writing to a pipe instead of the console.

Comment: @PeterLawrey So this is a piping problem? Actually I need to run `ifstat 120` in real-world environment...

Comment: The data doesn't appear to be delayed, only the heading.

Comment: @PeterLawrey OK, well, yes.. But why does the head delay to show?

Comment: I suspect it's not flushed explicitly.  When writing to the console it's auto flushed but when writing to a pipe it requires an explicit flush which it doesn't get until the first row of data appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does.

It is the output of the process that is delayed. STDIO does buffering, which varies according as stout is or isn't a terminal.

Comment: @coolcfan fflush() in the C program. Nothing you can do from outside.

Comment: The only thing you can do is download the source for ifstat, add a fflush() after the header is written and use that version instead.

Comment: It should be noted that some programs detect a tty and do less buffering when writing to a tty than other destinations (e.g. file or pipe).  You can create a pseudo-tty to reduce buffering even though the output isn't going to a terminal.

Comment: @EJP +1 for the " fflush() in the C program" this is the solution which I'm looking for 8 hours and finally got working. Still want to know why it is working? What does the trick?